# Redirect one domain to other with full query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 2 domains .com and .net.

I would like to redirect the .net to .com domain with the full URL, so just the domain changes.  For examples:

If a user visits:

```
http://www.example.net/images/myImage.png  he gets redirected (using 301 redirect) to http://www.example.com/images/myImage.png.
http://www.example.net/images goes to http://www.example.com/images
http://www.example.net/index.php?att=1&att=2 goes to http://www.example.com/index.php?att=1&att=2
```

I tried this:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.com$
 RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [L,R=301]
```

But if the query string (?att=1&att2=3...) isn't set it goes directly to www.example.com

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This always works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or, if you prefer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

If still nothing — try adding `QSA` flag (but it should work fine as is):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: In my setup, I had to remove the `/` forward slash before the `$1`. E.g. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301]`. Otherwise the redirect contained two forward slashes after the domain instead of one.

Comment: @UweKeim That may depend on where you've placed those rules. If placed in `.htaccess` then URL will not have the leading slash. If it's in a Apache config file, it will be present then. At very least that was the case back then in 2011.

Comment: Yes, in deed, I have mine in an Apache configuration file. Thanks for clarifing, taught me something new .